# Synonymise [pie] with [pie-chart]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie) and [pie-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-chart) are the same thing under different names:

> **pie**
>
> A pie chart is a circular chart divided into sectors, illustrating numerical proportion.

> **pie-chart**
>
> A pie chart is a circular representation of data divided into sections by the drawing of radii.

[image: Obligatory red pencil-width circles]

One has 179 questions, the other 841. There are [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie+pie-chart) which use both tags.

[pie-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-chart) is probably the more logical tag to keep...

Comment: Asking a moderator to review the `status-declined` wouldn't be correct, we can't implement those changes.  That was declined by a SE employee.  Plus including that in this request warps this one.  If you want a tag synonym then make this about that synonym request, don't make this a second request asking us to review something else as well.

Comment: The tag-wiki for `pie` is wrong. It should actually read *a baked dish which is usually made of a pastry dough casing that covers or completely contains a filling of various sweet or savoury ingredients* Anything mistagged as `pie` that is actually a `pie-chart` should be retagged, and anything tagged `pie-chart` that is actually about `pie` needs to be tagged `pie` and possibly eaten. (Am I doing it right?)

Comment: Don't put such an irrelevant intro into your synonym request :-/ Very tempting to just edit that out.

Comment: @bluefeet I see, I was under the impression StackOverflow moderators *are* SE employees. I've removed that part from the question.

Comment: @Cerbrus hardly irrelevant, given that there would be no need to post the question at all if the feature were to be implemented. Although I agree that it shouldn't neccessarily be the opener of the post.

Comment: @Cerbrus the reason I included it was because it partly is relevant. If that feature were not status-declined, but had in fact been implemented back in 2011, there would have been no need for me to post this here.

Comment: Mods are volunteers like the rest of us, CMs are employees :D

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yes, but who knows how many questions we would have gotten for "A bunch of users with no experience in this tag synonymized it to something else. Can it be reversed?" - While yes, there are *some* very obvious synonyms out there, not all of them are. And that feature only opens up the door for abuse in areas where they ought not be treading. It's a lot less irritating to have to get a moderator to make a synonym than have to get a moderator to *undo* one that shouldn't have been created.

Comment: @animuson isn't that the precise reason it's a system which users must first vote on before changes are applied?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly But that system fails if the users voting aren't familiar enough with the two tags to understand why they might not be synonyms.

Comment: @animuson wouldn't a 7.5k user (as the question proposes) know better than to make or vote for such changes though?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Not necessarily. If they believe they are synonymous and have no reason to think otherwise, why wouldn't they vote? They may be completely wrong, but they don't know that because they're not familiar with the tags. That's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I moved all the questions with the combination [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie) over to [css3pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3pie) which, despite its name, generally has nothing to do with pie charts.

The rest have been merged into [pie-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-chart). The [pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie) tag itself will be ditched since there are many other "pie" related tags on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Come 2020, [pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie) has resurfaced with 20 questions. However, a lot of these seem to be related to a new language called [Pie Language](http://thelittletyper.com/). I created a [pie-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-lang) tag for that.

Similarly, there were a lot of questions about Android Pie, which I tagged with [android-9.0-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-9.0-pie). The remaining were the ones related to Pie Charts, and I retagged them with [pie-chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-chart) instead.

For now, I have replaced the [pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie) with [pie-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pie-lang), so that the tag wiki (which isn't a great one, but anyway) is carried over.